# TypeError: (0 , _mantine_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.rem) is not a function next.js Dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mantine

I have a problem rendering a dropzone with next.js and mantine.
https://mantine.dev/others/dropzone/

import:
[image]

dropzone

[image]

error message

[image]

this is an code example of my problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/mantine-forked-kixzh7?file=/src/App.tsx

Maybe it's a problem with my node version? Currently, I use node 18.14.2

Comment: Please [don't use images of code9(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [provide a minimal reproducible example}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is being caused by nonmatching version of "@mantine/core" and "@mantine/dropzone".

Your `package.json` most likely looks like this.

```
...
"@mantine/core": "^5.9.4",
"@mantine/dates": "^5.9.4",
"@mantine/dropzone": "^6.0.1",
"@mantine/form": "^5.9.4",
"@mantine/hooks": "^5.9.4",
...
```

**To fix the error**, please go to your `package.json`, change the the "@mantine/dropdown"'s version to match the other package's version number then run `npm install` or `yarn install`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the error was like this when I tried to use Burger from mantine/core:

**TypeError: (0 , *mantine_hooks__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.useDisclosure) is not a function or its return value is not iterable**

I added "use client" to the component's file and error disappeared.

Comment: This fixed it for me. 

Which is a little concerning, as this is mentioned nowhere in the documentation or example files. Is this working correctly?

Comment: It is using a hook inside of itself propably and causing this error. It should be OK to mark it as "use client", I think.